# How do I reset the ScanStreamTransformer Accumulator?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am writing a Flutter application using the BLOC pattern. I'm currently trying to search a database and return a list of results on the screen.

The first search will complete fine. The issue is when I hit the back button and try to do a second search. The first search results aren't cleared out. Instead they remain on the screen and the new search results are placed below them.

In a nutshell here's what I'm doing.(I'm using the RxDart library)

1.) Defining input and output streams:

```
  PublishSubject<SearchRowModel> _searchFetcher =
      PublishSubject<BibSearchRowModel>();

  BehaviorSubject<Map<int, SearchRowModel>> _searchOutput =
      BehaviorSubject<Map<int, SearchRowModel>>();
```

2.) Piping the streams together in the class constructor.

```
_searchFetcher.stream.transform(_resultsTransformer()).pipe(_searchOutput);
```

3.) Adding the results to the fetcher stream

```
results.searchRows.forEach((SearchRowModel row) {
      _searchFetcher.sink.add(row);
    });
```

4.) Using a ScanStreamTransformer to create a map of the results.

```
_resultsTransformer() {
    return ScanStreamTransformer(
      (Map<int, SearchRowModel> cache, SearchRowModel row, index) {
        cache[index] = row;

        return cache;
      },
      <int, SearchRowModel>{},
    );
  }
```

From my debugging, I've found that the code in step 4 appears to be the issue. That cache (or the Accumulator) isn't getting reset between searches. It just keeps adding additional results to the map.

I've yet to find a way of resetting the map in the accumulator / cache that works. I even tried completely destroying the streams and recreating them, but the original search data in the SearchstreamTransformer accumulator still persisted.

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: Sort of... It's partially due to the way that the BLOC is scoped. So if you leave it at global scope, the stream is never going to be emptied. Unfortunately though, scoping the block down the the specific screen it's used on causes different issues.

This is by far not the best solution, but I created a Map property in the Bloc that I update via the stream. Whenever I need to reset the screen, I just manually empty the map. 

I'm confident this is the worst possible fix, but I was never able to find anything better.

Comment: @ragingprog, aren't you missing a `Future` in that `_resultsTransformer()`?